# Implicit differentiation of "similar" functions

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function

The graph of the equation $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ gives a circle of radius $1$, centered at the origin:

[image]

After we find its derivative:
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} (x^2 + y^2) = \frac{dy}{dx} 1 \\
2x + 2y \frac{dy}{dx} = 0 \\
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{x}{y}
$$
if we graph it on a 3D space we get this shape:
[image]
and it does describe the slope of the circle (positive in quadrant II & IV, negative in I & III)

Now let's consider a "similar" equation:
$$ x^3 + xy^2 = x $$
The graph should be same everywhere except when $x = 0$, since it's just the last equation multiplied by $x$ on both sides, and the differentiability of it should be the same except at $x = 0$

[image]

However, if we work out the derivative of y with respect to x:
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} (x^3 + xy^2) = \frac{dy}{dx} x \\
3x^2 + y^2 + 2xy \frac{dy}{dx} = 1 \\
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{3x^2+y^2-1}{2xy}
$$
we get a completely different function, and plotting the graph yields this weird shape:
[image]
and it doesn't describe the slope of the circle at all. So why does finding the derivative of the first equation works, but not the second?

Comment: On the curve you have $x^2+y^2=1$...

Comment: They’re not “similar,” though. Your second equation is that of the union of an _ellipse_ and the $y$-axis instead of the unit circle. Try again without that coefficient of $2$ that snuck into the second equation.

Comment: The correct equation $ \ x^3 + xy^2 \ = \ x \ $ was used in OP's calculation of the derivative; they apparently made a typo on the line you refer to.  The graph shown is also for the correct equation.  I have edited a correction to that line.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between the two derivatives is entirely due to the introduction of the vertical line $ \ x = 0 \ $ that is combined with the circle.  The derivative for the second "curve" is
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} \ \ = \ \ \frac{1 \ - \ 3x^2 \ - \ y^2 }{2xy} \ \ = \ \ \frac{(\overbrace{1 \ - \  x^2 \ - \ y^2}^{= \ 0}) \ - \ 2x^2 }{2xy} \ \ = \ \ -\frac{ x^2 }{ xy} \ \ . $$

For points on the circle that are not on the $ \ y-$axis, both derivative expressions produce the same result:  for example, at $ \ ( -\frac45 \ , \ \frac35 ) \ , $ we have
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} \ \ = \ \ -\frac{-\frac45}{\frac35} \ \ = \ \ \frac43 \ \ \ \ \text{versus} \ \ \ \frac{dy}{dx} \ \ = \ \ \frac{1 \ - \ 3·\frac{16}{25} \ - \ \frac{9}{25} }{2·\left(-\frac45 \right) ·\frac35} \ \ = \ \ -\frac{\frac{ - 32}{25} }{\frac{24}{25}} \ \ = \ \ \frac43 \ \ . $$

For the circle, we simply find horizontal tangents at $ \ (0 \ , \ \pm 1) \ \ , $ while $ \ x^3 + xy^2 \ = \ x \ \ $ has an indeterminate "value" $ \  -\frac{ 0^2 }{ 0·y} \ $ at all the points on the $ \ y-$axis [it is ambiguous at $ \ (0 \ , \ \pm 1) \ \   $ because there are both horizontal and vertical tangents at those points].